# Looking for a "remote wipe" software package for Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, security, geo-location

I'm looking for a solution that would allow me to locate a stolen or lost Windows 10 PC, and initiate a remote data wipe.  We can't use the built in Windows 10 location feature as we don't log in with Microsoft creds.

Thank you.